# Typescript как вернуть тип ключа

Tags: javascript, typescript

Пишу рендерер и не могу найти инфы, как правильно вернуть именно тип определённого свойства типа, передавая ключ в другом поле.

Может кто подскажет или укажет, что не так делаю? :(

```
type TUser = {
    age: number,
    initials: {
        name: string
    }
}

type TRendererFunctionArgs<TValues> = {
    value: TValues[keyof TValues],
}

type TRenderer<TValues> = {
    name: keyof TValues,
    renderer: ({ value }: TRendererFunctionArgs<TValues>) => string,
}

const renderer : TRenderer<TUser> = {
    name: 'initials',
    renderer: ({ value }) => value.name, // <--- Тут проблема, т.к. value : value: number | {name: string}
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html

Comment: Проблема в том, что value в агрументе функции содержит тип number или {name: string}, а нужно, чтобы он был только number, если name: 'age', или только {name: string}, если name: 'initials'

Answer (score 0):

```js
type TUser = {
    age: number,
    initials: {
        name: string
    }
}

type TRenderer<TValues> = { [K in keyof TValues]-?: {
    name: K;
    renderer: ({ value }: { value: TValues[K] }) => string;
} }[keyof TValues];

const renderer : TRenderer<TUser> = {
    name: 'initials',
    renderer: ({ value }) => value.name
}
```